# К чему приведут частые ошибки во время автоматических проверок в очереди проверок?

Tags: обсуждение

В шапке вопроса тавтология, но не придумал, как сформировать правильнее. Речь об автоматически сгенерированных проверках на внимательность. Чисто теоретически, что будет, если в течение некоторого достаточно долгого промежутка времени заваливать (принимать неверные решения) 100 из 100 проверок?

Comment: Ничего не будет.

Comment: Undefined behavior

Comment: Была замечена корреляция с общим количеством завершённых проверок. aleksandr barakin специально заваливает все аудиты (могу ошибаться), но бан в очередях так и не получил.

Answer (score 6):

Автоматически временно запретят участвовать в новых проверках такого типа.

Comment: @Эникейщик считает иначе. Так где же правда?

Comment: @V-Mor, в зависимости от полезности пользователя.

Comment: @V-Mor И тем не менее запретят. Вот пример на мета мете (найден по Failed audit): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342698/5752652

Comment: @Grundy, а какие-то более чёткие критерии где-то описаны? Насколько должен быть полезен/бесполезен пользователь, чтоб ему запретили/не запретили проверять после N-ного кол-ва заваленных проверок?

Comment: @V-Mor Grundy скорее недокументированные критерии имел ввиду - отсутствие в списочке, "на глазок".