# В каких случаях применяется блокировка доступа к очередям проверок?

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, инструменты-модератора, аудит

Cуществует два механизма блокировки доступа участников к очередям проверок:

1. Автоматическая (по итогам аудитов).
2. Ручная (с помощью инструментов модератора).

По автоматической есть [очень скудная информация по Ru.SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10765/337980). По ручной, нет никакой (см [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11750/337980), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11514/337980)).

Я интересуюсь критериями (численными или абстрактными) автоматической и ручной блокировки, которые в данным момент применяются на Ru.SO.

NB: этот вопрос сугубо для установления статус-кво и не имеет непосредственной цели его обсуждения. Очевидно, что с очередями проверки в нашем датском королевстве не все в порядке (см. связанные с этим вопросом темы справа), но стоит понять откуда растут ноги.

Comment: Что-то модераторы молчат. Или у них тоже нет соответствующей информации и нужен хотя бы сотрудник компании?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ по пункту 2 - они точно могут ответить сами. Видимо, не хотят, ибо я привлекал внимание к этому вопросу очень многими способами, включая пинг модератора в чате и просьбу обсудить вопрос внутри команды модераторов.

Comment: Модераторы уже не те. БольшаяМаленькаяСобачка.jpg